# Ruby Design Pattern Question - Classes/Modules Inheritance

Tags: ruby, oop, class, module

Right now I have:

```
module A  
  class B
    def initialize
       @y = 'foo'
    end  
  end
end

module A   
  class C < B
    def initialize
       @z = 'buzz'
    end   
  end
end
```

How can I have it so when I instantiate C @y is still set equal to 'foo'? Do I have to repeat that in the initialize under C? I am a following a bad pattern? Should @y be a class variable or just a constant under the module? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `super` keyword. It calls your parents definition of the same method.

I added params just in case. **Note**, to pass params B#initialize will have to take optional params as well.

```
module A   
  class C < B
    def initialize(params = nil)
       super(params) # calls B#initialize passing params
       @z = 'buzz'
    end   
  end
end
```

Comment: `super` without an argument list just passes the original arguments along anyway, so you could just say `super` instead of `super(params)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A::C < B
   def initialize( x, y )
     super # With no parens or arguments, this passes along whatever arguments
           # were passed to this initialize; your initialize signature must
           # therefore match that of the parent class
     @z = 'buzz'
   end
end
```

Or, as @EnabrenTane pointed out, you can explicitly pass along whatever arguments you know the super class will be expecting.

For more on inheritance, see the section on [Inheritance and Messages](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http%3A//phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_classes.html%23inheritanceandmessages) in the old-but-free online version of the Pickaxe book.